# Task serialisation error when using UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use IntelliJ IDEA to execute the code shown below. The content of `df` is the following:

```
+------+------+
|nodeId|   p_i|
+------+------+
|    26|0.6914|
|    29|0.6914|
|   474|   0.0|
|    65|0.4898|
|   191|0.4445|
|   418|0.4445|
```

I get Task serialization error at line `result.show()` when I run this code:

```
class MyUtils extends Serializable {
  def calculate(spark: SparkSession,
              df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

    def myFunc(a: Double): String = {
      var result: String = "-"
      if (a > 1) {
        result = "A"
      } 
      return result
    }

    val myFuncUdf = udf(myFunc _)

    val result = df.withColumn("role", myFuncUdf(df("a")))

    result.show()

    result
  }
}
```

Why do I get this error?

**Update:**

This is how I run the code:

```
object Processor extends App {
    // ...
    val mu = new MyUtils()
    var result = mu.calculate(spark, df)
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `myFuncUdf` declared twice in your code? Please produce a [mcve].

Comment: This code will give an error on val myFuncUdf = udf(myFuncUdf _)

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz: It doesn't give me error in the line `val myFuncUdf = udf(myFuncUdf _)`. Only in `result.show()`.

Comment: Can you show the entire object or class that includes the above code? How do you run it? Can you show the entire stacktrace since it should've contained the reference(s) to unserializable objects?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: I had to add `extends Serializable` to the specification of a class `MyUtils`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `extends Serializable` to the specification of a class `MyUtils`.